# Generate dynamic images based on the values in a column of data

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find a way to automatically generate images in a column based on the values in another column (The application is adding rebar images to an excel file that is exported from BIM software).

I have managed to get dynamic images using the 'define name' tool to define a name with the following formula:

=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4;MATCH(Sheet1!$F$2;Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4;0))

I have linked an image to this formula to make it dynamic. However I am stuck on the last step, where I want to apply this principle to an entire column where each image is based on the value in column F in its corresponding row. I have tried adjusting the formula to

=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4;MATCH(Sheet1!$F$2:$F$500;Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4;0))

But this did not change the behavior.

I was hoping to have the column of dynamic images change based on the cell next to it (so if I paste the column of dynamic images in column G I want the image in G5 to be based on the value in F5, G6 based on F6, ...)

All the images are however based on the value in F2.

[What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T5Im.jpg)

Sample file: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/94a6b73b1bd8408638f614c4bd965dee20191031090453/e01ddc

Comment: Could really use some help with this one :)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I know you need to use image links. Indirect might work, but I haven't figured it out yet.

This is the only thing that I have found but it would require a defined name for each row: 
computergaga.com/blog/create-a-picture-lookup-in-excel

Let me know if you find something better